# Xamarin: Import one page from a different solution using MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a Xamarin app using MvvmCross and I would like to exclude one page to a different Solution. 
Is that possible at all? 
I get following error displayed:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'Could not find view for TestApp.ValidationViewModel2'
```

Details:
I've got a main app where I would like to navigate to the external page "ValidationViewModel2".

```
new MvxAsyncCommand(async() => await NavigationService.Navigate<ValidationViewModel2>())
```

To reach the page in the new solution I added a reference to the 'TestApp' assembly.
The 'TestApp' solution contains a a single C# project containing a "ValidationPage2.xaml" and a "ValidationViewModel2.cs" file. The two files find each other and the project builds successfully.

I can also debug from my main page into the 'ValidationViewModel2' constructor; The error occurs afterwards.
I'm using only Android. My ValidationViewModel2.cs has also references to the main app.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you using .NET 2.0 standard project?

Comment: Yes, both projects use .Net 2.0 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study the documentation for MvvmCross a bit you will find the [documentation about Customizing App and Setup](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/customizing-using-App-and-Setup?scroll=140#providing-additional-view-and-viewmodel-assemblies).

This doc describes that if you want to put ViewModels or Views in different assemblies than the default ones MvvmCross expects, you need to tell MvvmCross about it.

This can be done by overriding your Setup.cs file per platform.

For Views:

```
protected override Assembly[] GetViewAssemblies()
{
    var list = new List<Assembly>(base.GetViewAssemblies());
    list.Add(typeof(SomeTypeFromAdditionalViewAssembly).Assembly);
    return list;
}
```

For ViewModels:

```
protected override Assembly[] GetViewModelAssemblies()
{
    var list = new List<Assembly>(base.GetViewModelAssemblies());
    list.Add(typeof(SomeTypeFromAdditionalViewModelAssembly).Assembly);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: The MvvmCross documentation is not correct: The method must be "public" and the return type must be "IEnumerable<Assembly>".

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to override only one of both methods. Overriding both methods led to an exception -> The same Assembly (dll) was Imported twice.